# reading special lines in lua

Tags: lua, line

I am searching for the easiest way to read a string which is located in a file with a variable number of lines behind:

> UserName=herecomesthestring

I thought about hardcoding a the linenumber, but this won't work, because in this file, the UserName can be more then once and the line numbers aren't the same (from user to user they may change).

Comment: You want to read the X lines from a file before a specific line in the file?

Comment: Seems you want to read lines until you match it with a pattern. Is that rght?

Comment: Let's say the file contains 13 lines of UserName=tom... all these lines are variable in the meaning of the contained username. The 'prefix' UserName= stands before EVERY username. I search for an easy way to return all the usernames. An array would be the best. sample output: {tom,peter,jack}

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file line-by-line
2. Match the line and extract the username
3. Put it in a list

```
function getusers(file)
    local list, close = {}
    if type(file) == "string" then
        file, close = io.open(file, "r"), true
    end
    for line in file:lines() do
        local user, value = line:match "^([^=]+)=([^\n]*)$"
        if user then -- Dropping mal-formed lines
            table.insert(list, user)
            list[user] = value -- Might be of interest too, so saving it
        end
    end
    if close then
        file:close()
    end
    return list
end
```

Call with either a file or a filename.

Comment: Is my use of the function right? `local f = assert(io.open('file2.ini', "r"))
local t = f:read("*all")
getusers(t)`

Comment: Not quite. Anyway, changed it: Now you can call it with either the filename or the file, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the function above a bit, now it works more or less, just need to edit the RegEx.

```
function getusers(file)
local list, close = {}
    local user, value = string.match(file,"(UserName=)(.*)")
    print(value)
    f:close()
end
```